# Need help authenticating to SVN repo with Cake

Tags: svn

I'm working on a semi-automated build process using SVN (hosted in CloudForge) and Cake.  I am new to Cake, so I thought I'd start with something simple.

Here's what's in my build.cake file:

```
#addin "Cake.Svn"

 var settings = new SvnCheckoutSettings();
 var creds = new SvnCredentials();
 creds.Username = "uname";
 creds.Password = "pwd";
 settings.Credentials = creds;

 var result = SvnCheckout(
         new Uri("https://cloudforge_repo"),
         @"c:\local_dir", settings);

     Verbose("Revision: {0}", result.Revision);
```

When I run the build.ps1 file, I get this result:

```
Preparing to run build script...
Running build script...
The 'addin' directive is attempting to install the 'Cake.Svn' package
without specifying a package version number.
More information on this can be found at https://cakebuild.net/docs/tutorials/pinning-cake-version
It's not recommended, but you can explicitly override this warning
by configuring the Skip Package Version Check setting to true
(i.e. command line parameter "--settings_skippackageversioncheck=true",
environment variable "CAKE_SETTINGS_SKIPPACKAGEVERSIONCHECK=true",
read more about configuration at https://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/configuration)
The assembly 'Cake.Svn, Version=0.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
is referencing an older version of Cake.Core (0.28.0).
For best compatibility it should target Cake.Core version 0.33.0.
Error: One or more errors occurred. Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://cloudforge_repo'.
```

What is the proper way to authenticate to an SVN repo using Cake?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is associated with the server certificate this is the complete message" SharpSvn.SvnRepositoryIOException: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted"